# Change properties of table when I send information from MySQL to webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql

I display the information of MySQL table in web, it's easy but I want to change the background color of a cell when it has certain value. In the example, my table has different fields: id, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, curso, e-mail, and direccion. I want to get that when the field curso = primero, the color of that cell was red.

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") ; 

if (!$connect) {
    die ("Can not connect: " . mysql_error () ) ; 
}

mysql_select_db("modelobdclase", $connect) ; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM datosalumnado";
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $connect) ;

echo  "<table border=1> 

<tr>
<th> id_alumnado </th>
<th> nombre </th>
<th> apellido1 </th>
<th> apellido2 </th>
<th> curso </th>
<th> fechadenacimiento </th>
<th> e-mail </th>
<th> direccion </th>
</tr>"; 
[B]
$valor= "primero"; 
function dame_color($valor) {
    if ($valor == 'primero') return 'red';
    else ' ';
}

while ($record = mysql_fetch_array ($myData)) {
    $color = dame_color($row->[B] 'curso' );

    [B]echo "<td bgcolor=$color>";
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $record ['id_alumnado'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record ['nombre'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record ['apellido1'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record ['apellido2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record ['curso'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record ['fechanacimiento'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record ['e-mail'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record ['direccion'] . "</td>"; 
}
echo "</table>" ;

mysql_close($connect) ; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$color = ($record ['curso'] == 'primero') ? "style='background-color:#f00;'" : '';
echo "<td $color>" . $record ['curso'] . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user 36.... it was a fantastic answer. It works!!

The complete code would be:

```
function dame_color($valor) {
      if ($valor == 'primero') return 'red';
     else return 'white';
    }  


while ($record = mysql_fetch_array ($myData)) {
$color = ($record ['curso'] == 'primero') ? "style='background-color:#f00;'" : '';


echo "<tr >";
echo "<td>" . $record ['id_alumnado'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record ['nombre'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record ['apellido1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record ['apellido2'] . "</td>";


echo "<td $color>" . $record ['curso'] . "</td>"; 


echo "<td>" . $record ['fechanacimiento'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record ['e-mail'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record ['direccion'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>" ;
```